# osculating plane for linear motion

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm reading section $14.8$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus, and he defines the unit tangent vector $T(t) = \frac{X'(t)}{\|X'(t)\|}$, whenever the speed $\|X'(t)\| \ne 0$.

Then he wrote that if motion is linear, $T' = 0$, but it is not clear to me why that is the case. I understand that by definition $\|T\| = 1$, so it cannot change the magnitude, and if the motion is linear, it cannot change the direction either, but still I cannot accept that statement completely, so I would appreciate if you could explain why it is actually 0 for linear motion.

For example, what happens if the particle moves up and down, so $T$ would be either 1 or -1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X(t)$ is linear then

$ X(t) = X_0 + f(t) V $

Therefore, the tangent vector is

$ X'(t) = f'(t) V $

And so the unit tangent is

$ T(t) = \dfrac{ f'(t) V }{\| f'(t)
( V \| } = \dfrac{f'(t) V}{ | f'(t) | \| V \| } = \text{sgn}(f'(t)) \ U  $

where $U$ is the unit vector along $V$.

Therefore, if $f'(t) \ne 0$, then  $T(t)$ is a **constant vector**.

Differentiate again,

$ T'(t) = \mathbf{0} $

because when differentiating a constant quantity the derivative is zero.

Comment: As mentioned in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4815307/942378, your answer assumes linearity in time, but it does not cover all motions along straight line in general. I guess we can assume that Tom Apostol also had in mind time linearity, so your answer is spot on.

Comment: I just read the section $14.6$ again, and the linear motion there is defined as $r(t)=P+f(t)A$, which means $r'(t)=f'(t)A$, $r''(t)=f''(t)A$. Then $T(t)=\frac{r'(t)}{\|r'(t)\|}=\frac{f'(t)A}{|f'(t)|\|A\|}=\frac{f'(t)}{|f'(t)|}\frac{A}{\|A\|}$. $\frac{f'(t)}{|f'(t)|} = 1$ or $\frac{f'(t)}{|f'(t)|} = -1$, so whenever the derivative exists, we know that $T'(t) = 0$.

Comment: Can you please just update the answer with that in mind, so I can accept it (e.g. for posterity not getting wrong impression about what linear motion is)?

Comment: @S11n I've updated the answer as you requested.