# Is $X(t) = X_0 + f(t)V$ linear motion?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4814133/942378) suggests that $X(t) = X_0 + f(t)V$ is not a linear motion, if $f(t) = t^2$, even if in 2D space (for example) represents a straight line.

Is that correct? If that's correct, what is the definition of the linear motion? What's the rationale?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on whether you consider linearity with respect to the spatial coordinates or the time variable. The answer you linked talks about being linear/affine with respect to $t$ actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you speak of linearity, I assume you mean linearity in time. Assuming $V$ is time independent and $X_{0}$ is constant, the equation of $X_{t}$ is second order in the time variable for $f(t) = t^{2}$ making it non-linear. The link you provided simply differentiates the function with respect to time to show that the order with respect to time is 1 in that particular example. In your example, the curve of $X$ vs. $t$ would not be a straight line but a quadratic. To define linearity, you need to be clear about the quantities you are referring to. Linear simply means that the order  (or equivalently the highest power) of the independent variable ($t$) is 1 in the governing equation of the dependent variable ($X$).

Comment: Just FYI, in Tom Apostol's book in chapter $14.6$ the linear motion is defined as $r(t)=P+f(t)A$.

Comment: Well it depends on how it defined $f(t)$ and again on the quantity with respect to which the linearity was defined.